# For or Foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to create 1 slice of code from the similar 3 paragraphs below?

The differences between each paragraph is:
* SQL Query WHERE Model = $
* $serie?? = new XYDataSet()
* addSerie("Model", $serie??)
* $serie??->addPoint

```
$chart = new LineChart(1800, 500);
$dataSet = new XYSeriesDataSet();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT Date, SUM(Qty_sum) AS Qty_sum FROM stats WHERE Model = 'ESD' GROUP BY MONTH(Date)");
    $serie1 = new XYDataSet();
    $dataSet->addSerie("ESD", $serie1);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $date = date('M', strtotime($row['Date']));
            $qty = $row['Qty_sum'];

            $serie1->addPoint(new Point("$date", $qty));
        }


$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT Date, SUM(Qty_sum) AS Qty_sum FROM stats WHERE Model = 'POSA' GROUP BY MONTH(Date)");           
    $serie2 = new XYDataSet();
    $dataSet->addSerie("POSA", $serie2);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
            $date = date('M', strtotime($row['Date']));
            $qty = $row['Qty_sum'];

            $serie2->addPoint(new Point("$date", $qty));
        }


$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT Date, SUM(Qty_sum) AS Qty_sum FROM stats WHERE Model = 'POSA MM/SAT' GROUP BY MONTH(Date)");            
    $serie3 = new XYDataSet();
    $dataSet->addSerie("POSA MM/SAT", $serie3);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
            $date = date('M', strtotime($row['Date']));
            $qty = $row['Qty_sum'];

            $serie3->addPoint(new Point("$date", $qty));
        }           


$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
```

Comment: Just FYI (`mysql_fetch_assoc` / `mysql_*`): This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. So you may go with some prepared statements in MySQLi or PDO_MySQL to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create an array,

```
$things = ['ESD', 'POSA', 'POSA MM/SAT'];
```

You could loop through the code 3 times, and replace the values where necessary.

i.e.

```
foreach($things as $thing){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Date, SUM(Qty_sum) AS Qty_sum FROM stats WHERE Model = '" . $thing . "' GROUP BY MONTH(Date)"); 
    $series[$thing] = new XYDataSet();
    $dataSet->addSerie($thing, $series[$thing]);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $date = date('M', strtotime($row['Date']));
        $qty = $row['Qty_sum'];

        $series[$thing]->addPoint(new Point("$date", $qty));
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this solves it... please beware that `mysql_*` is depricated

Comment: deleted my comment... but im talking about his whiles `$serie3->addPoint(new Point("$date", $qty));` he cant set them with the same object ^^

Comment: It would just be `$serie->addPoint(...)` and if it needed to be stored for later use, it can be assigned to an array `series[$thing] = $serie;`

Comment: you dont know why he has 3 series. may he needs them in further source. ATM hes has 3 and want to fill them with a loop. This is what you did but he will loose the 3 series in the end so simply use an array of series and everthing is fine.. i did the changes allready :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I'd write your code in one SQL query pass.

```
$chart = new LineChart(1800, 500);
$dataSet = new XYSeriesDataSet();
```

Make the models an array, to declare in one place.

```
$models = ['ESD', 'POSA', 'POSA MM/SAT'];
```

Create an array of series per model and initialize the dataset objects.

```
$series = [];
foreach ($models as $model) {
    $series[$model] = new XYDataSet();
}
```

Use PDO so you can use a parameterized `IN()` predicate in SQL. You need one placeholder per model, so generate the list of placeholders based on the size of your $models array.

I also do the date formatting in SQL (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
$placeholders = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($models), "?"));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT Model, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b') AS Mon, SUM(Qty_sum) AS Qty_sum 
    FROM stats 
    WHERE Model IN ($placeholders)
    GROUP BY Model, Mon");
```

It's easy to pass the array of models to the prepared query, to match the placeholders in the SQL query.

```
$stmt->execute($models);
```

The result set will be grouped by model as well as by month.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $point = new Point($row['Mon'], $row['Qty_sum']));
    $series[$row['Model']]->addPoint($point);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!